# API to pull an image from Imgur into a discord bot

Tags: javascript, api, discord, imgur

I am attempting to make an API that pulls images from imgur in order to run them through a discord bot using python that, in turn, posts that image in the discord server. I have some coding experience but have never made an API before and would like any and all advice or assistance.

I need to write the api that pulls the image from imgur so that it outputs it on a website to use as a webhook for the discord bot

In advance, thank you for your time, and have a pleasant morning, afternoon, evening, or night.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js gives a couple of examples of how to do this in their docs under `TextChannel.send`:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send

```
// Send a remote file
channel.send({
  files: ['https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/222078108977594368/6e1019b3179d71046e463a75915e7244.png?size=2048']
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to pull a specific category of images randomly from imgur.